# Global Memory vs. Dynamic Global Memory Allocation in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a CUDA (v5.5) application that will need to use global memory.  Ideally I would prefer to use constant memory, but I have exhausted constant memory and the overflow will have to be placed in global memory.  I also have some variables that will need to be written to occasionally (after some reduction operations on the GPU) and I am placing this in global memory.

For reading, I will be accessing the global memory in a simple way.  My kernel is called inside a for loop, and on each call of the kernel, every thread will access the exact same global memory addresses with no offsets.  For writing, after each kernel call a reduction is performed on the GPU, and I have to write the results to global memory before the next iteration of my loop.  There are far more reads from than writes to global memory in my application however.

My question is whether there are any advantages to using global memory declared in global (variable) scope over using dynamically allocated global memory?  The amount of global memory that I need will change depending on the application, so dynamic allocation would be preferable for that reason.  I know the upper limit on my global memory use however and I am more concerned with performance, so it is also possible that I could declare memory statically using a large fixed allocation that I am sure not to overflow.  With performance in mind, is there any reason to prefer one form of global memory allocation over the other?  Do they exist in the same physical place on the GPU and are they cached the same way, or is the cost of reading different for the two forms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Global memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-hierarchy) can be allocated [statically](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) (using `__device__`), [dynamically](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) (using device `malloc` or `new`) and via the [CUDA runtime](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory) (e.g. using `cudaMalloc`).

All of the above methods allocate physically the same type of memory, i.e. memory carved out of the on-board (but not on-chip) DRAM subsystem.  This memory has the same access, coalescing, and caching rules regardless of how it is allocated (and therefore has the same general performance considerations).

Since dynamic allocations take some non-zero time, there may be performance improvement for your code by doing the allocations once, at the beginning of your program, either using the static (i.e. `__device__` ) method, or via the runtime API (i.e. `cudaMalloc`, etc.)  This avoids taking the time to dynamically allocate memory during performance-sensitive areas of your code.

Also note that the 3 methods I outline, while having similar C/C++ -like access methods from device code, have differing access methods from the host.  Statically allocated memory is accessed using the runtime API functions like `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` and `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`, runtime API allocated memory is accessed via ordinary `cudaMalloc` / `cudaMemcpy` type functions, and dynamically allocated global memory (device `new` and `malloc`) is not directly accessible from the host.

Comment: Thank you, this exactly answers the question I had, plus a couple more I didn't even ask.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to think of coalescing the memory access. You didn't mention about the GPU you are using. In the latest GPUs, the coal laced memory read will give same performance as that of constant memory. So always make your memory read and write in coal laced manner as possible as you can.

Another you can use texture memory (If the data size fits into it). This texture memory has some caching mechanism. This is previously used in case when global memory read was non-coalesced. But latest GPUs give almost same performance for texture and global memory.

I don't think the globally declared memory give more performance over dynamically allocated global memory, since the coalescing issue still exists. Also  global memory declared in global (variable) scope is not possible in case of CUDA global memory. The variables that can declare globally (in the program) are constant memory variables and texture, which we doesn't required to pass to kernels as arguments.

for memory optimizations please see the memory optimization section in cuda c best practices guide http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/#memory-optimizations

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I'm using Tesla M2050s on Amazon AWS.  I understand the coalescing issues.  But is there any difference between coalesced reads from static vs. dynamically allocated global memory is the crux of the question I guess.  Also, I'm not sure about last line that says "the only globally declared variables are constant memory variables and texture."  According to this (https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-cc-kernels), there is global (variable) scope in CUDA global memory.  This link does not address my original question though.

Comment: for memory optimizations please see the memory optimization section in cuda c best practices guide http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/#memory-optimizations