# cudamalloc vs __device__ variables

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu

My question is what is the difference between variables using `cudaMalloc` and global `__device__` variables? I want to know whether there is any difference in:

- performance
- the way memory is allocated to them
- the way they are loaded to each thread for usage.

And I already know about difference in scope.

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything about this. (other questions are about `__global__` vs `__device__` "functions" which is not my concern here).

Comment: The really short  answer is no, no and no.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672111/global-memory-vs-dynamic-global-memory-allocation-in-cuda) seems relevant.  By the way, to find this all I did was put "cuda global static dynamic" in the search box at the top of this page, then arrange the results by votes.  It was at the top of the list